# R query: Error in (function(object,...) : missing values in 'weights'

Tags: r, survey

I am using R-studio and am trying to use the rbind function to return data to create a new variable that stores useful information.

I am currently working on a survey and have already installed these three libraries (survey) (openxlsx) (foreign).

The original data set I have read in is a CSV file containing 9000+ observations.

This is the error message that I keep receiving is:

> "Error in (function (object, ...)  : missing values in `weights'"

I have checked the definitions and functions script which details how the tables are created but I am unsure of how to correct the issue.

When I hit the show trace back option these few lines seem to come up often:

```
6.svydesign.default(ids = ~Area, strata = ~GOR, weights = ~weight, 
    data = DATA, nest = T) 

5.svydesign(ids = ~Area, strata = ~GOR, weights = ~weight, data = DATA, 
    nest = T) 

4.FUN(X[[i]], ...) 

3.lapply(rows, arciverfunc, table_type = table_type)
```

I would like to stop getting the error message and see the data being stored in the variable and be able to print the data when I try and run in the variable.

If anyone could help I would appreciate it.

Happy to provide more information if needed.

Thanks,

Comment: hi, maybe exclude rows with missing weights using  `DATA <- subset( DATA , !is.na( weight ) )`

Comment: Thanks for the help Anthony. Seems like the problem was due to NA values!